# custom email validation using javascript api with elementor pro and code snippets

Tags: customization, css, javascript, api

I am not very familiar with WordPress and CSS however, my system info is mentioned below:
php 8.0.7
wordpress 5.7.2
woocommerce 5.4.1
elementor pro 3.3.1
theme twenty-twentyone

my email provider is aws ses it won't provide any validation API.

I use code snippets to modify functions instead of the child themes to do some modifications.

now I use /log-in and /my-account for customers' login and registration, not the default one.I build that with essential addon but it won't provide the option to validate the login registration process in that flexible way.

now I am looking for email id validation where the visitors with aliased mail id should not able to register. eg. if any visitor holds an email id myname@gmail.com and creates an alias newname@my-company.com , he will not able to register with newname@my-company.com. I know that it is possible with javascript and some API to validate but I don't have exact information about it. now if I use the default email validation process it will just send an email to aliased mail id and the visitors will receive it through aliased mail id. so default validation won't work here just sending email without javascript validation. can anyone suggest the procedure with code snippets to achieve it w/o elementor pro within WordPress code snippets?

I don't want to use any plugin for such a thing.

thanks
sayantan

Comment: What's an aliased mail ID? Do you mean that your two examples are both hosted at gmail and both the same mailbox? I don't know how you'd ever find that out unless there's a gmail API you can query, and I doubt there is.

Comment: But if you think this is possible using JavaScript, can you point us to the JavaScript to see how it works?

Comment: it is there always lots of good vendors are using it. email aliasing is a very common thing. for example. someone purchased a domain from namehero GoDaddy etc. now that same person doesn't want to hold a mail id in that domain and creates an aliased email id that is pointing to their personal id. this validation is very common validation in govt / confidential projects/business 2 business where people don't want to receive spammed users. even if you create a group mail that can be validated also. it is completely done using the frontend itself. most of the partner's portals use this validation

Comment: OK. I still don’t know how you’re going to detect that. If you have an API or script you can use we can help you integrate it with WordPress. But I don’t think detecting aliasing would be possible.

Comment: still, I am optimistic and I can confirm it, it exists and it is possible. if I can mostly achieve anything I will post here.